# How can i add new row to com HTML object powershell

Tags: html, powershell, com

I have a table where i'm trying to add more rows with powershell then export it as a new HTML file.

Here's the body of the HTML i'm trying to add rows to.

```
<BODY>
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%" cellPadding=5>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TH>Bruger</TH>
<TH>Windows</TH>
<TH>Installations dato</TH>
<TH>Model</TH>
<TH>Sidst slukket</TH></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Users name</TD>
<TD>Windows 10 Pro</TD>
<TD>23-01-2020</TD>
<TD>ThinkPad</TD>
<TD>7 dage</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE>
<TBODY></TBODY></TABLE></BODY>
```

I figured i'd need to change the inner html of an object but it's just throwing an error.
Here's my code

```
$src = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($outPath)

$doc = New-Object -com "HTMLFILE"
$doc.IHTMLDocument2_write($src)

$elm = $doc.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0]
$elm.innerHTML = "<TR>New row!</TR>"
```

When I check the inner html variable I get the HTML output that I would expect, so it's grabbing the correct object, but I can't assign anything to it for whatever reason.

Here's the error

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0258
At line:1 char:1
+ $elm.innerHTML = "<TH>User</TH>"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Comment: With this type of situation it's better to change the data at the source.  The website is likely receiving some sort of structured data then converting to html.  FYI, it's way easier to convert to html than from html.  Strongly recommend you address this issue at the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the `innerHTML` contents of an *existing* `<tr>` element, you'll want to:

- Create a new `<tr>` element

  - Create any requisite `<td>` child element(s)
  - Append `<td>` element(s) to your new row
- Append the new row to the existing `<tbody>`

Try something like this:

```
$html = @'
<BODY>
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%" cellPadding=5>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TH>Bruger</TH>
<TH>Windows</TH>
<TH>Installations dato</TH>
<TH>Model</TH>
<TH>Sidst slukket</TH></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Users name</TD>
<TD>Windows 10 Pro</TD>
<TD>23-01-2020</TD>
<TD>ThinkPad</TD>
<TD>7 dage</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE>
<TBODY></TBODY></TABLE></BODY>
'@

# Create HTML document object
$doc = New-Object -ComObject HTMLFile

# Load existing HTML
$doc.IHTMLDocument2_write($html)

# Create new row element
$newRow = $doc.createElement('tr')

# Create new cell element
$newCell = $doc.createElement('td')
$newCell.innerHTML = "New row!"
$newCell.colSpan = 5

# Append cell to row
$newRow.appendChild($newCell)

# Append row to table body
$tbody = $doc.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
$tbody.appendChild($newRow)

# Inspect resulting HTML
$tbody.outerHtml
```

You should expect to see the new row appended to the table body:

```html
<TBODY><TR>
<TH>Bruger</TH>
<TH>Windows</TH>
<TH>Installations dato</TH>
<TH>Model</TH>
<TH>Sidst slukket</TH></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Users name</TD>
<TD>Windows 10 Pro</TD>
<TD>23-01-2020</TD>
<TD>ThinkPad</TD>
<TD>7 dage</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=5>New row!</TD></TR></TBODY>
```

You could create a nice little helper function for adding new rows:

```
function New-HTMLFileTableRow {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass]$Document,
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]$Property,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject
  )

  process {
    $newRow = $Document.createElement('tr')
    foreach($propName in $Property){
      $newCell = $Document.createElement('td')
      $newCell.innerHtml = $InputObject.$propName
      [void]$newRow.appendChild($newCell)
    }

    return $newRow
  }
}
```

Then use like:

```
Import-Csv .\path\to\user-os-list.csv |New-HTMLFileTableRow -Property User,OSVersion,InstallDate,Model,LastActive -Document $doc |ForEach-Object {
  [void]$tbody.appendChild($_)
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, thanks! One question though, how can I remove a row?

Comment: @Baxorr You're welcome! For removing nodes/elements, locate the parent element and remove the child node, eg. `$row1 = $doc.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1]; [void]$row1.parentElement.removeChild($row1)`

Comment: Dude you're amazing! I couldn't find any documentation on this anywhere

Comment: @Baxorr here's the trick: the HTML DOM is essentially a live XML document, so I just take the same approach I would if I was editing xml :)